# Проблемы с import name 'FromView'?

Tags: python, django

В процессе обучения... При запуске сервера (делаю регистрацию на сайте) вылетает такая проблема.

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "F:\django\test_django\courses_django\lesson_seventh\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "F:\django\test_django\courses_django\lesson_seventh\views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.views.generic.edit import FromView
ImportError: cannot import name 'FromView' from 'django.views.generic.edit' (F:\django\test_django\l
ib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py)
```

Жалуется на views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.edit import FromView
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .forms import UserCreateForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic.base import View
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from .forms import UserCreateForm
from lesson_sixth.models import Human
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login
""" Функция для установки сессионного ключа.
По нему Django будет определять, выполнил ли вход пользователь
"""
class MainView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'main_seventh.html'

    def get(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            humans = Human.objects.all()
            ctx = {}
            ctx['humans'] = humans
            return render(request, self.tamplate_name, ctx)
        else:
            return render(request, self.tamplate_name, {})


class RegisterFormView(FormView):
    form_class = UserCreateForm
    success_url = '/lesson-seventh/login/'

    template_name = 'register.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(RegisterFormView, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):

        return super(RegisterFormView, self).form_valid(form)

class LoginFormView(TemplateView):
    form_class = AuthenticationForm

    template_name = 'login.html'

    success_url = '/lesson-seventh/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Получаем объект пользователя на основе введенных данных
        self.user = form.get_user()

        # Выполняем аутентификацию пользователя
        login(self.request, self.user)
        return super(LoginFormView, self).form_valid(form)


class LogoutView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        logout(request)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/lesson-seventh/')
```

Как победить эту напасть ? Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Не надо использовать сниппеты где ни попадя. Это для яваскрипта, а не для всего подряд.

Answer (score 1):

У вас опечатка, должно быть `FormView`, а не `FromView`:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное... Пойду зрение проверю...((( Все действительно работает...